# Passing NULL variables to Perl from PHP?

Tags: php, forms, perl

I have a php page that I'm using a form on and passing the selections/data that is made on the form to a perl script that I created.  Unfortunately, when I pass the variables, if there are any empty variables my variables that I'm receiving on the perl script are not coming in at the right order.  Is there a way to make sure the variables that are being passed to the perl script are being giving the correct order whether there's data in them or not?

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
FTP/SFTP: <select name="TYPE">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="ftpd">FTP</option>
    <option value="sftpd">SFTP</option>
</select></t><Br>
Search String: <input type="text" name="SEARCH"></t><br>
Search Type: <select name="STYPE">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="user">Username</option>
    <option value="ip">IP Address</option>
    <option value="pid">PID</option>
    <option value="file">Filename</option>
</select><br>
Date (YYYY-MM-DD): <input type="text" name="DATE"></t><br>
Server: <select name="SERVER">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="test1ftp">test1</option>
    <option value="test2ftp">test2</option>
</select></t><Br>

<input type="submit" name="formSearch" value="Search">

</form></font></p>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the php portion that is calling the perl script:

```
<?php       
    if(isset($_POST['formSearch']) == "Search")
    {
        if(empty($_POST['SEARCH']))
            $_POST['SEARCH'] = "undef";

        if(empty($_POST['SERVER']))
            $_POST['SERVER'] = "undef";

        if(empty($_POST['DATE']))
            $_POST['DATE'] = "undef";


        //system("perl search.pl $_POST[TYPE] $_POST[SEARCH] $_POST[STYPE] $_POST[DATE] $_POST[SERVER]", $return_val);


    }
?>
```

When it gets to the perl script, I have the variables that are being passed go to the following.

```
my $TYPE = $ARGV[0];
my $SEARCH = $ARGV[1];
my $STYPE = $ARGV[2];
my $DATE = $ARGV[3];
my $SYSTEM = $ARGV[4];
```

So if I have no data in SEARCH it seems that the data that should have been passed to $DATE now ends up in $SEARCH.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote the command-line arguments. This will also be useful if the `$_POST[...]` variables have spaces in them:

```
system("perl search.pl \"$_POST[TYPE]\" \"$_POST[SEARCH]\" \"$_POST[STYPE]\" \"$_POST[DATE]\" \"$_POST[SERVER]\"", $return_val);
```